# selecting by count with one to many relathionship

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, join

So i do have User model and Cart model. obviously

```
User has_many :carts
```

and what i intend to do is selecting only users with specific carts count.
I really want to have it in pure rails-like-sql so i started with this:

```
User.joins(:carts).group(:id).count
```

which gave me a hash with pretty much all the information i need (user id and how many carts). however i dont want to browse again thorugh this hash, is there another smart and clean way?

Essentially I expect to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` with users who have more than 3 carts

Comment: what is the expected output and what's wrong with having hash?

Comment: expected output is ActiveRecord::Relation with users who have more than 3 carts. only thing wrong with hash is not being that;]

Answer (score 1):

To return AR with users, who have more, that 3 carts you would want to use [`having`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/having) clause:

```
User.joins(:carts).group('users.id').having('count(carts.id) > 3')
```

Comment: well i tested it and the results are incorrect (in a sense that i KNOW that there is more than 1 such user i got) , im gonna takie a closer look into 'having'

Comment: @Leo, you might be getting one user for each carts. try adding `.uniq` at the end, that will add a DISTINCT to your SQL.

Comment: over a hundred. actually it is really weird, because no matter which number i put in a place of '3', result is always the same

Comment: don't you need a `group` clause? In PostgreSQL this request would not work without an aggregate function, but I don't know about MySQL

Comment: it is definitely better, right know it gives me 81 results, so there are 26 more to get:D

Comment: same thing, 81 results, i know i need 107 because i test it with User.all.select {|u| u.carts.count > 3}.count

Comment: also, all the results i get are correct because i mapped them to carts count, and there isn o difference in results whether i use count(carts.id) or count(carts.user_id)

Comment: @Leo this is strange and I don't know yet what is the reason behind not getting right amount of users..

Comment: something is defnitely wrong with what we are doing, because no matter which cart attribute i put inside COUNT, the result is always the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join for that:

```
Cart.group(:user_id).count
```

What do you mean when you say "browse"?

Comment: thanks, good point but result i want i User relation, with all users who have, lets say 3 carts

Comment: Include that in your original question, so answers can be targeted to what you need.